# How to create a secure tunnel from my server <---> torserver.onion:port

Tags: onion-routing, tunnel

I need to create a secure tunnel from my server to the torsite.onion:port. As an example when I connect to myserver at myserver:port it will redirect to the tormailxxxxx.onion:25 for the tor email service.
I hope this solution will be really easy to do, but so far I couldn't find any sufficient solution.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Stunnel](http://stunnel.org) with full verification enabled (`verify=3` in config) and your local SSL microCA. For microCA I do recommend you to try either an OpenSSL perl scripts, or easyRSA as something more advanced.

Comment: Thanks Alexey for that stunnel part, but what about the way how to establish a connection itself ? Ssh/Stunnel probably can't resolve .onion adress itself. Thank you.

Comment: they won;t need to : as soon as you will connect through them *via Internet/clearnet* - they will *just forward the traffic to localhost* as they always can do. After that Tor plays it's role and makes a darknet part of the tunnel.